# How to run multiple Azure Functions projects locally as single app (on one port) on Docker?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-functions

I've inherited a project where there's around 15 projects in solution with Azure Functions in it. These are not 15 different function apps when deployed to Azure, rather (for example) first five projects are deployed to FunctionApp1, then next five to FunctionApp2 and final five to FunctionApp3.

This causes a lot of discrepancies when debugging locally, mostly with configs and dlls because when debugging locally we just run functions we require but when publishing we publish one project after the other and everything gets deployed eventually. Then, we merge the configs on function app level etc...

So what I want to do is to somehow have all functions from five projects **run on the same port and with joined configs**, as if it was deployed to Azure. I understand that this cannot be done via azure-cli, as far as I know, and that I need to containerize this? I've searched for quite a while to similar solutions but I didn't find anything useful...

Also want to mention that having them run "on the same port" is not a requirement per se (I can work around this via configuration) but I would like to simulate deployment of multiple projects with joined configs and dlls (if possible).

I know how to host a single app in a Windows' Azure Func container, but is it even possible to have all of these Function projects "published" to a container to simulate Azure's environment?

Comment: i'm pretty sure this goes against the container philosophy.

Comment: Hmm I see where you're coming at. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: container per function?

Comment: But this goes against a deployment strategy, which is why I want to containerize these functions. Also no, deployment strategy cannot change and functions are split this way because of dependencies' versions they're consuming (we have plenty NuGets developed by us).

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you will need to publish all the projects and merge the output. After that, run `func start` on that merged output.